# very complex shell string with a lot of quotes , how to deal with escape

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a string:

```
str='sudo nohup bash -c "kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "udp_receiver"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}'` > /nohup.out 2>&1 &"'
```

there are many quotes
and the above variable is not correct

I tried

```
str='sudo nohup bash -c "kill -9 `ps -ef|grep \"tcp\"|grep -v \"grep\"|awk \'{print $2}\'` > /nohup.out 2>&1 &"'
```

still not correct
how to modify it to make it correct?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str="sudo nohup bash -c 'kill -9 $(ps -ef|grep udp_receiver|grep -v grep|awk \"{print $2}\") > /nohup.out 2>&1 &'"
```

I haven't readily checked it, but this should be about it.

However, do look at `procps`'s `pkill` command

```
pkill -f udp_receiver
```

should do just the same. It automatically avoids the *self-kill* (see [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)). Also, note that you can query things first to test your pattern(s):

```
pgrep -fl udp_receiver
```

Comment: so the double quotes `"` in $() causes no problem when there are `"` outside?

Comment: Indeed. It is all down to the order of expansions. In fact you can `echo "$(pkill -f "$1")"` if you want to. Also see bash builtin `printf '%q'` by the way

Answer (score 0):

An interesting trick is to get away from traditional escapes to use interpolation to expand meta characters. I'll let you debug it and tweak to your environment.

```
sq="'";   #single quote
dq='"';   #double quote
xq='`';   #execution quote
dol='$';  #dollar sign
str="sudo nohup bash -c ${dq}kill -9 ${xq}ps -ef|grep ${dq}udp_receiver$dq|grep -v ${dq}grep$dq|awk ${sq}{print ${dol}2}$sq$xq > /nohup.out 2>&1 &$dq"
```